# A partial converse to Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

[Sloane's A077463](http://oeis.org/A077463/) obviously suggests that for any positive integer $n$ there exist $n$ consecutive primes and only them in  between $m$ and $2m$ for some natural number $m$.

For instance, for

$n=1$, take $m=2$;   $\hspace{.2in}$$2<3<4$;

$n=2$, take $m=7$;   $\hspace{.2in}$$7<11,13<14$;

$n=3$, take $m=9$;   $\hspace{.2in}$$9<11,13,17<18$;

$n=4$, take $m=15$;  $\hspace{.1in}$$15<17,19,23,29<30$,$\hspace{.1in}$ etc.

This problem offers a partial converse(given the number of primes, one seeks an exact interval $[m,2m]$) to Bertrand's Postulate(given an interval, one seeks at least one prime in it).

I would like to know

1. whether this problem is solved, or
2. whether there are stronger known conjectures to which it is a consequence.

Thanks, as always

Comment: Are you asking to prove that for every $n$ there is an $m$ so that there are exactly $n$ primes in $[m,2m]$?

Comment: @Gjergji, if possible, yes. 

Comment: I gave a simple proof that the statement is valid.

Comment: This seems a bit too easy for MO. But since you got an answer anyway, I see no point in closing...

Comment: @Gjergji, it just turned out simple, but I think I can keep it open by including some observations now such as there may always exist  an $m$ for every $n>10$ such that $f(m)=f(m+1)=f(m+2)=\ldots=f(m+k-1)$ for $k$ at least $3$. But let me think about it first.

Comment: It's fine, I don't mean to discourage you from asking further questions, that's why I commented earlier if this was really what you meant to ask. As for your observation, it is still in the easy territory, think about how one constructs arbitrarily large strings of consecutive composites.

Comment: Related: [Erdős's theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Erd.C5.91s.27s_theorems)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider the function $f(m):=\pi(2m)-\pi(m)$ which counts the number of primes $m< p \leq 2m$. It is easy to see that $f(m+1)-f(m)$ equals $-1$ or $0$ or $1$ depending whether $m+1$ and $2m+1$ are primes. On the other hand, by simple estimates for prime numbers, it can be seen that $f(m)$ tends to infinity. Therefore $f(m)$ takes all positive integer values.

EDIT: Of course the same holds for $\pi(2m)-\pi(m-1)$ which counts the primes in $[m,2m]$.

Comment: @GH, I understand that $f(m)$ tends to infinity, but I do not see why it might not jump some big numbers. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @Elohemahab, read the proof carefully, especially the part about $f(m)$ never changing by more than 1 when you add one to $m$. 

Comment: The jump $f(m+1)-f(m)$ equals $1$ if $2m+1$ is prime but $m+1$ is not, equals $0$ if both or none of $2m+1$ and $m+1$ are prime, equals $-1$ if $m+1$ is prime but $2m+1$ is not. All cases are covered here.

Comment: Forgive my laziness. The problem no longer exists. Thanks very much.